# How do I expand the number between 0.1 and 0.22 to larger distance 0 and 1?

Tags: matlab, range, max, intervals, min

I have a map (`512x512`) that has values is between `0.119` and `0.2499` and I want to use it as a probability map so I need to expand this distance to `[0,1]`. How can I do it and map the first map's value into `[0,1]`?

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far and what you have tried? Can you also include an [mre]

Comment: Thank you. I think I find the answer. I use mapminmax function and map my values into a new range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Manually scaling:    No Toolbox Required**
Following a number of posts with this ([1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/281162/177387), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5294955/8239061), [3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/178626/177387), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36000843/8239061)),

If your numbers `x` currently lie on the interval `[xmin xmax]`, the code below completes the following steps<sup>[a]</sup> to map to `[a b]`:
1. `x - xmin` maps `x` to interval `[0 xmax-xmin]`,
2. `(x-xmin)./(xmax-xmin)` maps `x` to the interval `[0 1]`; note that `x = xmin` are now 0 and `x = xmax` are now 1,<sup>[b]</sup>
3. Multiplying `(x-xmin)./(xmax-xmin)` with `(b-a)` now maps `x` to the interval `[0 b-a]` (note element-wise multiplication `.*`),
4. Adding `a` to `((x-xmin)./(xmax-xmin)).*(b-a)` shifts that interval to `[a b]`.

Note this requires `xmax > xmin` to avoid division by zero. Also requires `b > a` to avoid mapping everything to `a`.

```
xmin = 0.119;               % current lowerbound for data
xmax = 0.2499;              % current upperbound for data    (xmax > xmin)
a = 0;                      % target lowerbound (under new scale)
b = 1;                      % target upperbound

A = xmin*ones(512) + (xmax-xmin)*rand(512);          % generate example current data

fh=@(x) ((x-xmin)./(xmax-xmin)).*(b-a)+a;            % rescaling function

A2 = fh(A);
```

You can compare `min(A(:))` and `max(A(:))` with `min(A2(:))` and `max(A2(:))`, respectively.

**Using [`mapminmax()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/mapminmax.html):    Deep Learning Toolbox Required**
A close look at the documentation for [`mapminmax()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/mapminmax.html) (see "Algorithms") shows the above process is exactly what this function is doing. Just replace `[ymin ymax]` below with `[a b]` and compare to the above "manually scaling" approach provided. Note [`mapminmax()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/mapminmax.html) has an additional assumption (copied below).

> It is assumed that X has only finite real values, and that the elements of each row are not all equal. (If xmax=xmin or if either xmax or xmin are non-finite, then y=x and no change occurs.)
>
> `y = (ymax-ymin)*(x-xmin)/(xmax-xmin) + ymin;`

So the appropriate use would look like

```
A3 = mapminmax(A,a,b);
```

<sub>[a] Credit to @[S.Kolassa - Reinstate Monica](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/1352/s-kolassa-reinstate-monica) for [this excellent answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/281164/177387).</sub>
<sub>[b] Since you desire `[0 1]`, this is all you need. I've given the more general case for those seeking interval `[a b]` with `b > a`.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I want to map my values in a matrix to a new range and I used `mapminmax` function for this aim and it works for me. if you have other suggestions please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: You're right!  The [`mapminmax()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/mapminmax.html) does this.  See my answer for detailed explanation.