# OpenCV Python: Normalize image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV. I want to do some preprocessing related to normalization. I want to normalize my image to a certain size. The result of the following code gives me a black image. Can someone point me to what exactly am I doing wrong? The image I am inputting is a black/white image

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

img = cv.imread(path)
normalizedImg = np.zeros((800, 800))
cv.normalize(img,  normalizedImg, 0, 255, cv.NORM_MINMAX)
cv.imshow('dst_rt', self.normalizedImg)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Is your image using a bitdepth other than 8bit? if so you'll need to convert it to 8bit to display it.

Comment: img.dtype gives me uint8 @zeFrenchy

Comment: I hope you mean the image is grayscale, not actually black and white, ortherwise normalizing will do nothing. Does it work with NORM_L2?

Comment: Sorry if my terms are not correct. What I meant to say is that my image is binarized. the pixel values are either (0, 0, 0) or (255, 255, 255). I am not sure if that is part of grayscale; in class, the prof told us there was a difference between grayscale and binarized

Answer (score 20):

as one can see at: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.normalize, there is a `→ dst` that say that the result of the `normalize` function is returned as output parameter. The function doesn't change the input parameter `dst` in-place. 
(The `self.` in `cv.imshow('dst_rt', self.normalizedImg)` line is a typo)

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
path = r"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Hydrangeas.jpg"
img = cv.imread(path)
normalizedImg = np.zeros((800, 800))
normalizedImg = cv.normalize(img,  normalizedImg, 0, 255, cv.NORM_MINMAX)
cv.imshow('dst_rt', normalizedImg)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How do you normalize all the image set? Should you regard on each image by itself or one normalization over all images?

Comment: It depends if "alpha" and/or "beta" are variables or fixed values. if they are variables (like the over all min and max of the image set values) - over all images (but you need to calculate alpha and beta in advance). if they are fixed - each image by itself.

Comment: if dst is returned by cv2.normalize as a output parameter, why does dst is also taken as input parameter? @OphirCarmi

Comment: this is a good question, maybe because of the c++ api of this function

Answer (score 10):

It's giving you a black image because you are probably using different sizes in img and normalizedImg.

```
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread(path)
img = cv.resize(img, (800, 800))
cv.normalize(img, img, 0, 255, cv.NORM_MINMAX)

cv.imshow('dst_rt', img)
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Update**: In NumPy there are more intuitive ways to do this [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735025/how-to-normalize-a-numpy-array-to-within-a-certain-range):

```
a = np.random.rand(3,2)

# Normalised [0,1]
b = (a - np.min(a))/np.ptp(a)

# Normalised [0,255] as integer: don't forget the parenthesis before astype(int)
c = (255*(a - np.min(a))/np.ptp(a)).astype(int)        

# Normalised [-1,1]
d = 2.*(a - np.min(a))/np.ptp(a)-1
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `cv.imshow()` you use `self.normalizedImg`, instead of `normalizedImg`.

The self. is used to identify class members and its use in the code you've written is not appropriate. It shouldn't even run as written. However I assume this code has been extracted from a class definition, but you must be consistent in naming variables and `self.normalizedImg` is different from `normalizedImg`.