# Rescale values in a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I have a 3 dimensional numpy array with values ranging from 0 to 1.06. I need to rescale them between 0 and 255. How to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to normalize a NumPy array to within a certain range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735025/how-to-normalize-a-numpy-array-to-within-a-certain-range)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just divide these by `1.06` and then multiply these with `255`. So if `a` is your array, you can construct a rescaled array `b` with:

```
b = 255 * a / 1.06
```

If you want to make these integers (or bytes), you can use:

```
(255 * a / 1.06).astype(int)
```

or `np.uint8` for bytes.