# How to convert a 0, 255 binary image to a 0, 1 binary image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I have an image `img` in the form

```
array([[  0,   0,   0, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   0,   0, ..., 255, 255,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ..., 255,   0,   0],
        ...,
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=uint8)
```

Is there any build in python function that convert images like that to 0,1 binarization?

Comment: Divide the image by 255.

Comment: See *
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735025/how-to-normalize-a-numpy-array-to-within-a-certain-range * for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using double for loop is completely inefficient. You can divide all by the max value (in your case 255) like this:

```
img = np.array(img/img.max(),dtype=np.uint8)
```

Another way is to define a threshold value and set all image values above this threshold to 1:

```
threshold = 0
img[img>threshold]=1
```

I recommend it because it will even assign values 1 in the binary image to values that were different to 255 in the original image.

Comment: note that the `img/img.max()` operation results in a temporary float array. you can just say `img /= img.max()` which will cause an in-place integer division (if `img` is of integer type)

Answer (score 0):

Your each row is a `list`, and from each list you want to check whether the value is `255` or not. If it is `255` convert to 1.

To get the index of each row and column , you can enumerate through the `list`

```py
for i, v1 in enumerate(img):
    for j, v2 in enumerate(v1):
        if v2 == 255:
            img[i, j] = 1
```

Result:

```py
[[0 0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0]]
```

Code:

```py
import numpy as np

img = np.array([[0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255],
                [0,   0,   0, 255, 255,   0],
                [0,   0,   0, 255,   0,   0],
                [0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
                [0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
                [0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0]], dtype=np.uint8)

for i, v1 in enumerate(img):
    for j, v2 in enumerate(v1):
        if v2 == 255:
            img[i, j] = 1

print(img)
```

Comment: this doesn't use numpy at all, other than numpy arrays as containers of numbers. the explicit looping makes this extremely slow. not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Simply divide whole image with 255 as treat as float,

img = img / 255.

Comment: note that the result of this will be of dtype `np.float64`